# xgboost model getfscore:'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, xgboost, callable

```
feat_imp = pd.Series(xgbPara.booster().get_fscore()).sort_values(ascending=False) 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I can run it in pycharm, but when I run it in pyspark, there is a Type Error.

could anyone tell me why? Thanks！

Answer (score 11):

Replace `xgbPara.booster()` with `xgbPara.get_booster()`, if that wont work, you have a version mismatch and you need to upgrade either sklearn, xgboost or both. Hope this helps.